# I want to know when a program written by Java is running,its classes will be all loaded on the main memory?

Tags: java, eclipse

When a program written in Java is running, will all of its classes be all loaded into the main memory? If so, isn't it a waste of RAM?

Comment: This is a fair question.

Comment: It's not in the memory, it's in the VM's memory which doesn't waste RAM unless it needs to.

Comment: Classes are not all loaded at start-up, but are loaded on-demand.

Comment: @aetheria Keep in mind that the exact timing of class loading is not defined by the specification. There is no guarantee of on-demand loading. Precise semantics exist only for class initialization.

Comment: Depends on what exactly is meant by loading... Certainly no eager loading in the sense of loading as defined by ClassLoader.loadClass(name). That will find the class, parse its binary and initialize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's fine, because of virtual address space and virtual memory. Read these:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space

Virtual memory means that you can load a large amount into memory and the unused sections are saved to disc and are moved out of physical RAM.

Virtual address space means that each process (one example of a process is your Java program) has its own address space, so it does not 'steal' addresses from other processes.

Answer (score 2):

Only classes that are referenced during a particular execution are loaded. Most large Java programs will frequently run with many of the classes not loaded as those classes serve various scenarios not exercised by that particular process.

Classes in the standard library are handled the same as application classes. For instance, if your application does not reference AWT, no classes in AWT packages will be loaded.

Java language spec contains the wording which explicitly precludes eager initialization of classes.

[JLS Section 12.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4):

> A class or interface type T will be
>   initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the
>   following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is
>     created.
> - T is a class and a static
>     method declared by T is invoked.
> - A
>     static field declared by T is
>     assigned.
> - A static field declared by T
>     is used and the field is not a
>     constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a
>     top-level class, and an assert
>     statement (§14.10) lexically nested

Note my use of the term "initialization". A class is initialized as part of constructing Class object, when parsing the binary data that defines the class.

There is nothing precluding a particular ClassLoader implementation from loading the binaries of all the classes that it sees into memory, but it cannot fully load those classes until they are requested without violating JLS.

For a common ClassLoader implementation, see URLClassLoader.

Comment: In fact there is no guarantee as to which classes will and will not be loaded by the JVM.

Comment: When executing a code path that references class X, you are guaranteed that JVM will load and initialize class X. In the inverse situation, you are guaranteed that JVM will not initialize class X unless executing a code path that references it. There are no guarantees made whether the class will or will not be loaded in this case, but in practical terms, no JVM implementation is going to waste resources loading classes that aren't necessary.

Comment: For one thing, a good part of the standard library will be loaded at startup. Also, as soon as a single class is accessed from a JAR, an implementation may optimize towards speed and load the entire JAR in one go.

Comment: @Marko, I added further info in the answer in response to your comment. Hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: Yes, class initialization has strict timing semantics. This is important because Java code is involved in it and the exact moment when it runs is important for program correctness. As far as memory is concerned, this only impacts the memory taken by static variables and objects assigned to them. The class code itself is already loaded into the permanent generation and in most cases its memory footprint dominates.

Comment: Can you reference a ClassLoader implementation that performs this eager loading? I'd like to see what API it uses to load the class without causing it to be initialized.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any references for you. The class loading logic is native functionality so I don't expect any interesting APIs you'll see.

Comment: The native API is driven by plain Java ClassLoader logic. Native code has no idea how to get it hands on class bits. It doesn't know anything about jars, etc.